# Unable to use output variables set in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline which uses a templated job as follows:

```
  - template: '/pipeline/templates/jobs/DeployInfraToRegion.yml@devops'
    parameters:
      ...
```

This job deploys a compiled Bicep template to Azure. This template creates a KeyVault and outputs its name as follows:

```
output sqlSecretsKeyVaultName string = keyvault.outputs.keyVaultName
```

The above template contains a single job named *DeployInfrastructure*:

```
jobs:
- deployment: DeployInfrastructure
  displayName: Deploy Infrastructure
  variables:
  ...
```

It runs a final task which takes all outputs and sets them as pipeline variables:

```
            - task: PowerShell@2
              name: SetArmOutputsForRegion
              displayName: "Set Arm outputs as variables"
              inputs:
                targetType: inline
                pwsh: true
                errorActionPreference: stop
                script: |
                  $armOutputString = '$(${{ parameters.armOutputVariable }})'

                  $armOutputObj = $armOutputString | convertfrom-json
                  $armOutputObj.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
                    $type = ($_.value.type).ToLower()
                    $key = $_.name
                    $value = $_.value.value

                    if ($type -eq "securestring") {
                        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$value"
                    } elseif ($type -eq "string") {
                        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;isOutput=true]$value"
                    } else {
                        Throw "Type '$type' not supported!"
                    }
                  }
```

Note that this task is named *SetArmOutputsForRegion*.

When this runs I can see in the pipeline out that this pipeline variable is being set as expected:

> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=sqlSecretsKeyVaultName;isOutput=true]expected-keyvault-name

After this templated job is run, the next job needs to use this output variable. I've configured it like this:

```
  - job: 'AddSecretsToKeyVault'
    dependsOn: DeployInfrastructure
    variables:
      keyVaultName: $[ dependencies.DeployInfrastructure.outputs['SetArmOutputsForRegion.sqlSecretsKeyVaultName'] ]
      ...
```

Note that this job depends on the job where the variables are set, and this is referenced as *dependencies.DeployInfrastructure*. The string is in the format *[task name].[variable name]* as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable). However, when I try to access this variable it is always empty:

```
    - task: AzurePowerShell@4
      displayName: Ensure required secrets exist
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: MyConnection
        failOnStandardError: true
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
        scriptType: 'inlineScript'
        inline: |
          Write-Host "Vault name is $(keyVaultName)"
```

I feel at this point I've tried every possible variant of the variable declaration. I've triple checked all the names, I've had all my code sanity checked by others. I just cannot understand why these variables are not available to me. Posting here in the desperate hope somebody can explain what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

I've now discovered [documentation about deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables), which apparently treat output variables differently. In my case I have a `runOnce` job, so I need to include the job name as a prefix. In other words, change...

```
    variables:
      keyVaultName: $[ dependencies.DeployInfrastructure.outputs['SetArmOutputsForRegion.sqlSecretsKeyVaultName'] ]
```

...to...

```
    variables:
      keyVaultName: $[ dependencies.DeployInfrastructure.outputs['DeployInfrastructure.SetArmOutputsForRegion.sqlSecretsKeyVaultName'] ]
```

However, having made this change, the variable value is still empty.

Could this have something to do with the variable being set by a templated job from another repo? I don't see how, but I honestly don't think I'm doing anything wrong :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally worked this out. Eventually solved it with a neat trick I'd like to share.

In the job where you need to use the output variables, add the following variable:

```
variables:
      checkDependencies: $[ convertToJson(dependencies) ]
```

Then add the following task:

```
    - script: "echo '$(checkDependencies)'"
      name: checkDependencies
```

This will print the whole `dependencies` JSON object to your pipeline output, allowing you to inspect the outputs and avoid all guesswork. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies), this object takes the format:

```
"dependencies": {
  "<STAGE_NAME>" : {
    "result": "Succeeded|SucceededWithIssues|Skipped|Failed|Canceled",
    "outputs": {
        "jobName.stepName.variableName": "value"
    }
  },
  "...": {
    // another stage
  }
}
```

In my particular case, it appears (by my reading) that the documentation I referenced in my **Update 1** is wrong. Performing the above check told me that I need to use this format to retrieve my output variable value:

```
$[ dependencies.DeployInfrastructure.outputs['Deploy.SetArmOutputsForRegionEun.sqlSecretsKeyVaultName'] ]
```

This solved the problem in my case. The documentation had suggested I needed to re-state the job name (`DeployInfrastructure`) as the variable name prefix, but actually I needed the work `Deploy` instead. Possibly I have misunderstood, but anyway the above trick should avoid any trial and error in future!

(Note that for cross-stage dependencies you can use the same inspection trick, but use the `stagedependencies` object instead of `dependencies`).

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful - the MS documentation is pretty opaque.  Surprised they don't include this debugging trick (or just include this info in the pipeline logs when you enable diagnostics...).